# Get object with generic type from interface that only sets the type in the method

Tags: c#, inheritance

This doesn't work:

```
public interface IServerFuncs
{
    Table<T> getTable<T>() where T : MasterClass;
    //*cut* other stuff here
}

public class DefaultFuncs<T> : IServerFuncs where T : MasterClass
{
    Table<T> table;

    public DefaultFuncs(Table<T> table)
    {
        this.table = table;
    }

    public Table<T> getTable()
    {
        return table;
    }
}
```

It sais `DefaultFuncs<T>' does not implement interface member 'IServerFuncs.getTable<T>()'`

But I can't do this either:

```
public Table<T> getTable<T>() where T:MasterClass
{
    return table;
}
```

It sais `Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'MySQLCache.Table<T>`. I guess T in the method clashes with `DefaultFuncs<T>` so I tried:

```
public Table<T2> getTable<T2>() where T2:MasterClass
{
    return table;
}
```

But it gives another error: `Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'Table<T>' to 'Table<T2>'`

I need to get this to work without adding a generic type to `IServerFuncs` (`IServerFuncs<T>`).. any ideas?

Comment: The base `getTable()` should not be generic.  Also, public member names should be UpperCamelCase.

Comment: There isn't a clean way of resolving this since `getTable` allows the client to choose the type `T` even though there's only one possible type that can be provided. If you can't make `IServerFuncs` generic, then your only options are to throw an exception if `T2 != T` or add a non-generic interface to `Table<T>` and return that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do

```
public Table<T2> getTable<T2>() where T2:MasterClass
{
    return (Table<T2>)(object)table;
}
```

if you know that T and T2 will always be the same type.  If they are not, you will get a runtime exception.

Comment: I'll see if I can work my way around this because it's messy, but it does do the trick.. thanks ;)

Comment: Why not say `where T2 : T` here? But in any case this is ugly. It seems very natural to make `IServerFuncs` generic (so `IServerFuncs<T>`) because you really don't want your **method** to be generic. Why don't you like `IServerFuncs<T>`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this without adding the template modifier to the interface, otherwise you could do this:

```
public class MC1 : MasterClass
{
}

public class MC2 : MasterClass
{
}

IServerFuncs df = new DefaultFuncs<MC1>(new Table<MC1>());
Table<MC2> table = df.getTable<MC2>();   // obviously not correct.
```

Basically, to guarantee that the same type is used by the interface and the implementation, you need to add the qualifier to the interface definition:

```
public interface IServerFuncs<T> where T : MasterClass
{
    Table<T> getTable();
    //*cut* other stuff here
}

public class DefaultFuncs<T> : IServerFuncs<T> where T : MasterClass
{
    Table<T> table;

    public DefaultFuncs(Table<T> table)
    {
        this.table = table;
    }

    public Table<T> getTable()
    {
        return table;
    }
}
```